# Use an Azure Functions managed identity to access Azure Web App API methods

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

I would like to use the managed identity of a Azure Functions app to authorize for a connection to a web app with some api methods.

The functions app and web app are both in Azure in the same tenant. The web app has app service authentication enabled and I can access the API using my personal Azure AD account. No roles have been defined.
I was using this guide to get a OAUTH token but have not yet succeeded authorizing the Functions App. As in the sample of [this](https://awhnet.medium.com/securing-api-to-api-azure-app-services-using-managed-identity-ea02035c7d0d) blog post I have been trying to use the web app url to set the context for the token request:

```
var context = new TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://your-integrationapi-url.azurewebsites.net/.default" });
```

This context url does not seem to work and I was able to get a token after adding a scope in the “Expose an API” menu in authentication settings in the Azure Portal. The scope url looks like “api://00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000”.
When I use this token in an authorization header the functions app tries to authenticate but gets an access denied error.
I have tried several ways to get a token using the DefaultAzureCredential, ManagedIdentityCredential and combined using the ChainedTokenCredential. Either way a token is received successfully but I doesn’t seem to be ok for authorization in my API.
I would like to know how to get this to work properly.

I have been trying to add a role and assigning it to the managed identity of the functions app using this guide but can’t get the powershell script to work either. This script fails with the following error:
Message: Entitlement with id: 61cc2c03-4625-4298-99d1-b09f13ea7fa1 does not exist on resource application e690e51c-6f21-4795-8450-04ebba17d60e.
But a role with the id is available in the manifest:

```
"appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User",
                "Application"
            ],
            "description": "Can access settings API",
            "displayName": "Use settings API",
            "id": "61cc2c03-4625-4298-99d1-b09f13ea7fa1",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "Settings.Update"
        }
    ],
```

I am not really sure if adding roles is a necessity. For now it’s ok that all identities in the tenant can access the API methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Azure app service and enabled System assigned identity.

[image]

- And exposed API , with scope `api://<clientId>/<scopename>`.
- Then requested the token with scope `api://<clientId>/.default`

[image]

When decoded the received token,

[image]

- If you observe issuer value , “iss” does not have V1 endpoint and aud value is like `api://<clientId>` , It must equal to the ClientId  or appId URI.
- So , it depends on what your API is expecting.
- So in allowed audiences  give both App Id Uri `api://<clientId>`  and ClientId .
- Also as issuer value has V1 endpoint, try to change the manifest , the manifest value to null or 1 ,if it is 2  , else change to 2.

[image]

Make sure to expose api with scope to your API:

[image]

And make sure it is granted admin consent.