# Use Managed Identity to access API from Function App

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I cannot obtain a token from the MSI ENDPOINT of a Function App to access an API deployed in Azure that uses the Easy Auth Authentication. I get 500 Internal Error.

I'm trying to use the Managed Identity activated on an Function App in Azure to get a token using the MSI_ENDPOINT. I'm using as a scope an api endpoint using the syntax: "api://<guid>/.default".
The API has an app registration and App Roles. I have assigned a valid role to the Managed Identity through the code:
`New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment`

In the Function App, I'm using this code to get the token:

```
var tokenCredential = new ManagedIdentityCredential();
var tokenResponse = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(
  new TokenRequestContext(new[] { scope }),
  cancellationToken
);
return tokenResponse.Token;
```

this code needs the namespaces Azure.Core and Azure.Identity to run properly.

When the code runs, I expect to receive a Token but rather the GetTokenAsync obtains: "Service request failed.Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)Content:{"statusCode":500,"message":"An unexpected error occured while fetching the AAD Token ...".

If I change the scope, using "https://vault.azure.net/.default", it runs with no errors.
The approach described in the following link ([Use an Azure Functions managed identity to access Azure Web App API methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74024852/use-an-azure-functions-managed-identity-to-access-azure-web-app-api-methods)) uses a confidential client flow (with clientid and secret) and it's not the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

For those that get into the same problem be aware of the proper flow:

1. enable the ManagedIdentity for the caller app
2. enable the EasyAuth authentication on the calling api
3. get to the app registration used by the Easy Auth and take note of the api scope (Expose an API)
4. get to the app registration used by the Easy Auth and create an App Role
5. as you cannot assign this role to the ManagedIdentity of the caller, use the New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment cmdled (you should run it using an user with the proper role in Azure AD)
6. when you try to get the token use the ManagedIdentityCredential class passing the api scope (api://guid) . Note: do not use the user_imeprsonation suffix
   7)optional - if the app registration used by the Easy Auth have the Require Assignment flag to yes, you must add the ManagedIdentity to the enterprise app's users (Enterprise App -> users -> add).

My mistake was using the user_impersonation suffix.
Please note I was able to get into the issue using this guide to troubleshooting the Azure.Identity library: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/README.md#logging